# Components: What is the purpose of the option_on and option_off fields in models > forms > viewname.xml?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, xml, component-params

In a Joomla 3.x component, a parameter that's frequently listed in the MODELS > FORMS > VIEWNAME.XML file is `option_on` or `option_off`.

For example;

```
<field
    name="something_amazing"
    type="editor"
    label="COM_YOURNAME_FORM_LBL_VIEWNAME_SOMETHING_AMAZING"
    description="COM_YOURNAME_FORM_DESC_VIEWNAME_SOMETHING_AMAZING"
    menu_published="0"
    filter="safehtml"
    option_on="Yes"
    option_off="Yes"
/>
```

Many of the available parameters are listed on the [official documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types), but no matter where I look, I can't seem to find an explanation of these particular fields.

What are they for, and can you give an example of when you might use them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In which component did you find that parameter?

Comment: I noticed those fields too, but only in components created with http://www.component-creator.com. So you could ask them instead. And tell us all about it here :-)

Comment: I couldn't find even one such instance in Joomla core files. So it must be from third party components you are using.

Comment: @COBIZ - "By Jove, Holmes, I think you've cracked it!".  Feel free to post that as an answer and I'll give you the tick - otherwise, I'll take a closer look and report back on its exact purpose in the next day or two.  Thank you all for clarifying that it's not specific to Joomla, though - most helpful.  ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These options are generated (only) by extensions created with [component-creator.com](http://www.component-creator.com/en/).